# Сохранения цены для определенной категории?

Tags: yii2

Привет всем.

Не получается сохранить цену для определенной категории.....пользователь выбирает свою специальность сохраняет, потом его переводит на другую вкладку для проставки цены или если пользователь решил изменить цену (ЦЕНА ДОЛЖНА ОТОБРАЖАТЬСЯ В ИНПУТЕ) то он меняет значение...вроде все, НЕ МОГУ ПОНЯТЬ КАК МНЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

controller:

```
public function actionProfile()
{
 ....
    $price = ($price = ProfileHasCategory::findAll(['user_id' => 
 $user_id])) ? $price : new ProfileHasCategory();

    return $this->render('profile', [
         .......................
        'price' => $price,
    ]);
 ....
 }
```

view:

```
<?php foreach ($price as $k) : ?>
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><?= $k->category_id ?></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <?= $form->field($k, 'price')->textInput()->label('') ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><?= Html::submitButton('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::end() ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
public function actionProfile()
{
    ....

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $id = (int)Yii::$app->request->post("phc_id");
        if ($id) {
            if (($model = ProfileHasCategory::findOne($id)) === null) {
                throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException();
            }
        } else {
            $model = new ProfileHasCategory();
            $model->user_id = $user_id;
        }
        // Нужно проверить может ли юзер менять значение по этому id, например так, если нет модераторов и настройки RBAC:
        if (!$model->isNewRecord && $model->user_id != $user_id) {
           throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException();
        }
        //Сохраняем. В rules у модели для безопасности оставить только price, или настроить сценарии, или сделать отдельную модель-форму
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->save();
        }
    }

    $price = ($price = ProfileHasCategory::findAll(['user_id' => $user_id])) ? $price : new ProfileHasCategory();

    return $this->render('profile', [
         .......................
        'price' => $price,
    ]);
 ....
 }
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($price as $k) : ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
        <?= \yii\bootstrap\Html::hiddenInput("phc_id", $k->id); ?>
        <?= $form->field($k, 'category_id')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><?= $k->category_id ?></td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <?= $form->field($k, 'price')->textInput()->label(false) ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><?= Html::submitButton('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::end() ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе все работает!

Answer (score 0):

При составлении ActiveForm, полям формы можно присваивать дефолтные значения:

```
<?= $form->field($k, 'price')->textInput(['value' => 'Дефолтное значение здесь']) ?>
```